# Full-Width Vimeo Embed non-responsive

Tags: html, css, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have embedded a vimeo within a `div` that is the full-width of the viewport. The video worked perfectly for a couple of days but now the play button (and all other buttons) are completely non-responsive.

I've tried messing around with the `z-index` but that doesn't work.

```
<div class="full-screen-vid">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/192013765" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

.full-screen-vid {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw;
   margin-top: 90px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

There is a strange message I've been getting in the console which I looked up and tried to fix but I don't think it is the problem (or the whole problem) because if I remove the video from the `full-screen-vid`, it works correctly.

Console message:

```
Refused to load the script'data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1bmN0aW9xxxxIGZ1…xxxxxxxxxxxx=' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
https://f.vimeocdn.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://f.vimeocdn.com".
```

Comment: Why are you loading the iframe inside the div? Why don't you just give the iframe the CSS for full-screen-vid?

Comment: good suggestion however i still have the same problem

Comment: actually - doing that and chaning the `z-index` did work, thank you! if you put it in as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `<iframe>` stand-alone, adding the `full-screen-vid` class to it, should work.